# Bash jq modify json : get and set

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I use jq to parse and modify cURL response and it works perfect for all of my requirements except one. I wish to modify a key value in the json, like:

A) Input json

```
[
    {
        "id": 169,
        "path": "dir1/dir2"
    }
]
```

B) Output json

```
[
    {
        "id": 169,
        "path": "dir1"
    }
]
```

So the last directory is removed from the path. I use the script:

```
curl --header -X GET -k "${URL}" | jq '[.[] | {id: .id, path: .path_with_namespace}]' | jq '(.[] | .path) = "${.path%/*}"'
```

The last pipe is ofcourse not correct and this is where I am stuck. The point is to get the `path` value and modify it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `split` and `join` to process the path, and use `|=` to bind the correct expression to the `.path` attribute.

```
... | jq '.[] | .path|=(split("/")[:-1]|join("/"))
```

- `split("/")` takes a string and returns an array
- `x[:-1]` returns an array consisting of all but the last element of `x`
- `join("/")` combines the elements of the incoming array with `/` to return a single string.
- `.path|=x` takes the value of `.path`, feeds it through the filter `x`, and assigns the resulting value to `.path` again.